# Is there a word processor that I could use where if I hover over an image link, it will display the image within the word processor?

Tags: word-processor

In other words, what I'm asking is this: Does there exist a word processor that upon hovering over an image link, displays the image within the word processor without navigating me outside the word processor or re-directing me to a browser webpage?

Comment: And on what OS should it work, how much may it cost?

Comment: I think your wanted feature doesn't supported on any word processors (Microsoft Word?) so you have to manually click an image link if you want to display that image.